# Cannot install Android studio on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, android-studio

When trying to install the 32 bit packages required for running Android Studio on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit Desktop PC using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

I am getting the following messages

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32bz2-1.0 : PreDepends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.9-18) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32ncurses5 : Depends: lib32tinfo5 (= 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
                Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32z1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Output of

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

are following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 avahi-daemon : Depends: bind9-host but it is not going to be installed or
                         host
                Recommends: libnss-mdns but it is not going to be installed
 gconf-service : Depends: gconf-service-backend (= 3.2.6-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 gvfs : Depends: gvfs-daemons (>= 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2)
        Depends: gvfs-daemons (< 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2.1~)
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
 libncurses5:i386 : Depends: libtinfo5:i386 (= 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
                    PreDepends: libtinfo5:i386 (>= 5.9-3) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: libgpm2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base:i386 (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 python3 : Depends: python3.4 (>= 3.4.0-0~) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python3-minimal (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have also tried

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

but I get following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base:i386 (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Try "sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386"

Comment: Got errors. updated question with output

Comment: Using aptitude solved the problem.
sudo aptitude -f install lib32stdc++6
Choose 'n',then choose 'Y' when prompted.

Comment: @cosmicraga Thankyou so much mate! Your solution worked.